# Excel, Min/Max macro different range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to develop hopefully a short macro for someone not too good with code for the following.

I have a file similar to the attached but much much bigger.

For those wondering its FMEA scoring.

I want to take the maximum value of each set of yellow cells * the value of the blue cell * minimum value of the red cells and display just that value in the green cell.

For the amount I have listed i appreciate its easy just to write the formula in. But as I said the file itself is much larger, and as I have tried to show the columns are all different lengths so i cant just look at say 5 rows and copy the formula down as it will not be in the right place.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

[image: img1]

Comment: I have a hard time believing that a macro would be easier than a formula here - How many rows are you working with? Is there always a completely empty row between your data sets?

Comment: somewhere between 2-12 rows in a "set" overall the best part of 10,000.
Ideally yes an empty row. and if not I can put them in easily enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does assume that 19 is the max number of items in a group.

Put this in H2 and copy down:

```
=IF(A2<>"",MAX(C2:INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C2:C20)/(C2:C20=""),1)))*E2*MIN(G2:INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(G2:G20)/(G2:G20=""),1))),"")
```

If 19 is not the max number in a group change the `20`s to the max number of items per group.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is an open break between each "Title Block", the following should work for you.  It can be entered as a formula, all that needs to be done is create a new macro, and paste the code from below into the code window.

```
Function minMax(ByVal rRange As Range, MinOrMax As String) As Double
Dim dMin As Double
Dim dMax As Double
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lLastRow = ws1.Cells(rRange.Row, rRange.Column).End(xlDown).Row

dMin = ws1.Cells(rRange.Row, rRange.Column).Value
dMax = dMin

For Each cell In rRange.Cells
    If cell.Value < dMin Then dMin = cell.Value
    If cell.Value > dMax Then dMax = cell.Value
Next cell

    If InStr(1, MinOrMax, "min") = 1 Then
        minMax = dMin
    Else
        minMax = dMax
    End If

End Function
```

To use this custom function, enter into the cell where you want the value as "=minMax(B1:B10, "min")" where the second argument should be either a quoted Min or Max.  Typing "Min" will yield the minimum of the range and "Max" will yield the maxvalue of the range.  This function will support unlimited arguments and is case insensitive.